# Cannot retrieve shader binary

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm having problem retrieving shader program's binary.

I made a class named "Building" that has the following static members:

```
  static GLenum binary_format;
  static unsigned char * program_binary;
  static GLsizei binary_size;
  static GLsizei binary_length;
```

I use program_binary to store the shader program,
I made these members static in order to retrive their values from
any instance of the class, once the first instance fills them with proper values.
This class also has the following member method, which I use as routine to setup the shader program :

```
 void Building::setShaders()
  {     


    if(program_binary == nullptr)
      {


    shader_prog = glCreateProgram();

    GLchar const *vss[]=
      {
        *smanager.getVShaderSource(0),
        *smanager.getVShaderSource(1)       
      };

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs,2,vss,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);


    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs,1,smanager.getFShaderSource(0),NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);


    //CHECKING COMPILE STATUS
    GLint vs_status;
    glGetShaderiv(vs,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&vs_status);

    GLint fs_status;
    glGetShaderiv(fs,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&fs_status);


    if(vs_status == 0 || fs_status == 0)
      {

        if(vs_status == 0)
          {
        GLint log_length;
        glGetShaderiv(vs,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&log_length);
        char log[log_length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs,log_length,NULL,log);
        printVShaderLog(log);
          }

        if(fs_status == 0)
          {
        GLint log_length;
        glGetShaderiv(fs,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&log_length);
        char log[log_length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fs,log_length,NULL,log);
        printFShaderLog(log);
          }

      }


    else
      {

        glAttachShader(shader_prog,vs);
        glAttachShader(shader_prog,fs);
        glProgramParameteri(shader_prog,GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_RETRIEVABLE_HINT,GL_TRUE);        
        glLinkProgram(shader_prog);

        GLint param;
        glGetProgramiv(shader_prog,GL_LINK_STATUS,&param);

        if(param)
          {
        printShaderLinkState(param,NULL);

        glGetProgramiv(shader_prog,GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH,&binary_size);

        std::cerr<<"binary_size is "<<binary_size<<std::endl;
        //binary_size is zero !

        program_binary = new unsigned char [binary_size];
        glGetProgramBinary(shader_prog,binary_size,&binary_length,&binary_format,program_binary);

          }
        else
          {

        GLint logLength;
        glGetProgramiv(shader_prog,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&logLength);
        char log[logLength];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_prog,logLength,NULL,log);
        printShaderLinkState(param,log);        
          }



      }


    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

            }//if(program_binary == nullptr)
        else        

 glProgramBinary(shader_prog,binary_format,program_binary,binary_length);



  }
```

The problem is that the length provided by  `glGetProgramiv(shader_prog,GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH,&binary_size);`
is zero.However, I tried to put binary_size = 100 just to see if something is written into the program_binary pointer, but the function `glGetProgramBinary(shader_prog,binary_size,&binary_length,&binary_format,program_binary);` isn't working either, in fact program_binary remains just empty. I have no clues why this is happening .

Comment: Does your OpenGL implementation support more than zero `GL_NUM_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS`?

Comment: thanks! yes , you'r right, my openGL implementation supports 0 binary formats...what to do ?

Comment: Switch to an implementation that supports more than zero or live without binaries.

Comment: @genpfault thanks!